# pass NULL to php mysql where clause

Tags: php, mysql

One of the column in table has been set as `NULL`, will contain or won't contain value. 
Now, if user input is `NULL` then select all row that contains `null`. If in case of non-empty input, then select accordingly.

```
WHERE student.section = NULL // tried like '', 'NULL'
```

But I found this is not a valid way

So I do following logic, but I thought it is not well-structured, I thought it can be shorten, to prevent repetitive code.

if `section` is null

```
if(empty($_POST['section'])){
    $result=$con->prepare(
        "SELECT
        ...
        FROM student
        WHERE student.class=:cid AND student.section IS NULL"
    )
    $result->bindParam(':cid',$_POST['class']);
    $result->execute();
} else {
    $result=$con->prepare(
        "SELECT
        ...
        FROM student
        WHERE student.class=:cid AND student.section=:sid"
    )
    $result->bindParam(':cid',$_POST['class']);
    $result->bindParam(':sid',$_POST['section']);
    $result->execute();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problme, `IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, code is working, there is no problem. I am trying to to reduce code.

Comment: if  `student.class=:cid` and `student.section=:sid` then how can you do the same thing with "reduced code".  Alias the tables?  `FOME student s WHERE s.section=:sid` that's the only thing i can think of that desn't change the logic.  Of course if you are not joining there is no need to put the table in again anyway...

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, of course I am using join.. you mean it is better to use join here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the superficial table usage. If there are no joins you don't need to put it in again, this will make it "shorter" but keep the same logic.

```
SELECT
    ...
    FROM student
    WHERE class=:cid AND section=:sid
```

There I saved you about 14 keystrokes and`0<14` so it's "reduced".

I know I said `IS NOT NULL` in the comments but logically there is a difference between

```
  AND student.section=:sid
```

AND

```
  AND student.section IS NOT NULL
```

IF `student.section = 10` and `:sid` is 20, you won't get the record, but if you change it to `IS NOT NULL` then you will because `10` certainly is not null, but it's also not 20, and thus the logic has been changed.  In once case you don't get a record in the other you do.

**UPDATE**

This is the only other thing I can think of

```
$sql = 'SELECT
    ...
    FROM student
    WHERE class=:cid AND section';

if(empty($_POST['section']))
    $sql .= ' IS NULL';
else
    $sql .= ' = :sid';

$result=$con->prepare($sql);
$result->bindParam(':cid',$_POST['class']); //this is wrong
$result->execute();
```

**UPDATE1**

But, you really shouldn't do this either.

```
$result=$con->prepare($sql); //this is PDOStatment not a result
$result->bindParam(':cid',$_POST['class']); //this is wrong
$result->execute(); //your not setting a result variable
```

Also it will be hard to conditionally bind to `stmt (PDOStatment object)` because you don't yet have it when the query is being constructed.  You could do `prepare` 2x and bind to `cid` 2x. You could do the condition 2x, and then bind in the second condition. But, we are shorting it and fortunately we can pass the arguments in as an array for `execute`.

So I would change that to use an array of parameters

```
$sql = 'SELECT
    ...
    FROM student
    WHERE class=:cid AND section';

$param = [':cid' => $_POST['class']];

if(empty($_POST['section'])){
    $sql .= ' IS NULL';
}else{
    $sql .= ' = :sid';
    $param[':sid'] = $_POST['section'];
}

$stmt=$con->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute($param);

$data = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ALL);
```

The way you worded the question made it difficult to understand.  This is just basically DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principles which is good.  Unlike WET (Write Everything Twice) ... lol.  So when someone says your coding is all WET you know what they mean now. :)

In fact I was so confused I almost missed the `$result` issue.

Cheers!

Comment: @AnandHmt - I had to think it though, So sure thing and Good luck and Happy coding and all that Jazz.  lol

Comment: Really to be honest I almost never use `bindParam` the only time is when I need to bind to the `LIMIT` because that only works if you tell it's an INT, which you cant do with `execute` .  The difference is  `execute([':limit' => 1])` = `LIMIT '1'` and `bindParm(':limit', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT)` = `LIMIT 1` the quotes mess it up.  Even then it's fairly safe to just do `$limit = (int)$limit` or `$limit=intval($limit)` because if it's not an `int` it typically gets turned into `0` sometimes it might turn into another number, maybe ;-/

Answer (score 1):

When selecting NULL values you shouldn't use equal statements. You should use IS statements, like so:

For null values

```
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE status IS NULL;
```

or for not null values

```
SELECT foo
FROM bar 
WHERE status IS NOT NULL;
```